# Jenkins docker:command not found

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on my local machine which runs on MacOS High Sierra and have docker installed . I am trying to run a simple pipeline example which uses docker. I have added the following lines to pipeline :

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker 'node'
    }
    stages {
        stage("testing 123") {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then from the WebGUI, I click on build now and it is failing. Console output showing the error `docker: command not found`. The complete error log is as follows :

```
Started by user Happycoder
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ docker inspect -f . node
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/test@tmp/durable-20ded4c0/script.sh: line 2: docker: command not found
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ docker pull node
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/test@tmp/durable-ebdc1549/script.sh: line 2: docker: command not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Why this is happening ?  In the Jenkins documentation, they are only given this syntax and doesn't mentioned about anything else.

Comment: Is the docker service running?

Comment: Yes Docker is running.

Comment: So you have a local Docker image tagged with "node"?

Comment: nope. I don't have. It should pull one right ?

Comment: Now the error has changed to Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory after adding shell path and docker path

Answer (score 2):

I think the following section is not correct:

```
agent {
  docker 'node'
}
```

This command will try to launch a Docker container associated with the 'node' label.

If you want to test a declarative pipeline, you should try this syntax (if you want to build a Maven project):

```
agent {
  docker {
    image 'maven:3.5.0-jdk-8'
  }
}
```

FYI, you can find a lot of pipeline examples [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples).